# How do I get this array of double to print without error?

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors, double

I was given a code to copy and paste which was the code below except with double replaced to int. I am supposed to make it into a double so I replaced everything and still am receiving a possible lossy conversion error. Do you guys know what is wrong?

```
public class InitializingNumericgArray
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
      double [] doubleValues;
      doubleValues = new double[10];

      for(double n = 0; n <= 9; n+= 1)
        {
           System.out.println("index position " + n + " = "
           + doubleValues[n]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Indices for arrays are integers. Do not use a double for that.

Comment: Indices for array are integers...change your for loop accordingly

Comment: Suggest adding a language tag.

Comment: i changed the for loop, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Mistakes are:

1. declaration syntax of array is incorrect
2. Loop variable n must be integer because all values of n is converted to double ex. 0 becomes 0.0, 1 becomes 1.0 and so on. Therefore the next line of code

   doubleValues[n] //is interpreted as doubleValues[1.0] which is wrong

This is code with corrections:

```
public class InitializingNumericgArray
{
     public static void main(String []args)
     {
          double []doubleValues;
          doubleValues = new double[10];

          for(int n = 0; n <= 9; n+= 1)
          {
               System.out.println("index position " + n + " = "
                + doubleValues[n]);
          }
     }
 }
```